# How to get websocket url (subscripionsUrl) from apolloserver constructor

Tags: websocket, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have this code  and i try to charge the subscription in apollo playground but i cant it, I also tried to import 'PubSub' from apollo-server but this didn't work, I also tried to follow the documentation but it gave the same result, I have been reading in many places but no solutions; I must emphasize that the subscriptionsUrl returns me undefined and according to what I investigate it should be something like 'ws://...',

not if my code is a bit old or what happens

i'm trying make the subscription executed in loop but i receive the response

```
{
  "message": "server must support graphql-ws or subscriptions-transport-ws protocol"
}
```

the typeDefs and  resolvers is declared in the same file that server variable, does anyone know what to do?

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

import './mongo.js'

import {
  ApolloServer,
  AuthenticationError,
  gql,
  UserInputError
} from 'apollo-server'


import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions'

import Person from './models/person.js'
import User from './models/user.js'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const { JWT_SECRET } = process.env

const SUBS_EVENTS = {
  PERSON_ADDED: 'PERSON_ADDED'
}

const pubsub = new PubSub()

const typeDefs = gql`...`

const resolvers = {...}

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const auth = req ? req.headers.authorization : null

    if (auth && auth.toLowerCase().startsWith(`bearer `)) {
      const token = auth.substring(7)
      const { id } = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET)
      const currentUser = await User.findById(id).populate('friends')


      return { currentUser }
    }

  }
})

server.listen().then(({ url, subscriptionsUrl }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`)
  console.log(`Subscriptions ready at ${subscriptionsUrl}`)
})
```

```json
// in the json
{
  "name": "graphql-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "jsonserver": "json-server --watch db.json",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "3.10.3",
    "axios": "1.1.3",
    "dotenv": "16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^2.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "6.7.0",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "3.1.0",
    "uuid": "9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "0.17.0"
  }
}
```